# My iPhone & my daughters iPhone are getting the same text messages

Tags: iphone, text

I just restored a phone from back up for my daughter.  Now my text messages say they are from her.  We both have IOS 7, and share an Apple ID.

Comment: Could you explain what "my text messages" means? Is a SMS you send from your iPhone to someone else using your daughter's caller ID? This doesn't make sense with the title saying you both receive the same SMS from elsewhere?

Comment: Your problem is that you are sharing an Apple ID, you each need to have a personal one.

Answer (score 5):

guessing - they're iMessages & both are using the Apple ID rather than just the individual phone number…

though I still don't think it's very wise have 2 people's devices using the same ID, [Family Sharing](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) would seem a better option.

Try removing the ID as an iMessage source, leaving just the phone number, on at least one of the devices…

[image]

Comment: its important under send and receive.... to use individual numbers!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be because you and your daughter use the same Apple ID. Remove the ID in iMessage.

> get the same text if my doughter gets from her friend,she uses my Apple ID. How can I solve the problem

All you need to do is to apply for a new ID for her on https://appleid.apple.com/.

Answer (score -3):

do you mean iMessage messages? Try deleting the account from you one phone unter Settings->iMessage.